# Free animated gifs for web: loading and progress bars/spinners

Tags: website-design, animation, gif, free

Where is the best place to find free animated gifs?

I have tried googling 'free animated gifs' but the sites that come up offer just useless gifs such as balloons or something in that direction. I'm looking for web design gifs such as a loading bar etc.

Comment: Have you tried Googling "loading bar animation" or "progress bar animation"? https://www.google.com/search?q=progress+bar+animated+gif&espv=210&es_sm=122&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=nE4PU8bKBoS3kQfM14CoBw&ved=0CCYQsAQ&biw=1280&bih=963

Comment: yes and im finding some but theyre not quite good enough, often lacking in resolution and other things.

Comment: this one is quite good: http://glenmartinmusic.com/mustache/wp-content/themes/glenmartin/images/loader.gif

Comment: Yeah, you'll just have to get more specific with your search. Once you see a type you like, search for those elements and it should help. For instance, with your example above I'd refine my search for "circular loading animation". https://www.google.com/search?q=progress+bar+animated+gif&espv=210&es_sm=122&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=nE4PU8bKBoS3kQfM14CoBw&ved=0CCYQsAQ&biw=1280&bih=963#q=circular+loading+animated+gif&tbm=isch

Comment: If you still can't find one you like, you may just have to create one. You can use anything from Photoshop to Flash to After Effects to do something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are after loading bars etc, i can suggest

[**ajaxloader**](http://www.ajaxload.info/) - you design your own

**[preloaders](http://preloaders.net/)** - same thing

These sites will give you spinners, bars, balls etc.

[**And this post should also answer your question I think.**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27054/graphic-element-to-show-on-a-form-while-user-awaits-response/27055#27055)